# How to dual boot linux on windows 10 Huawei matebook X Pro from GRUB load screen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, grub

I just need some help with code I'm trying to dual boot linux on my laptop from a USB stick. I had to disconnect Secure Boot for it to work, but when I try to install it I'm opened with a Grub screen.
I am fairly certain my OS lies on hd0 disk, though there is hd0,msdos1, that I'm not sure what it is, but when I try to boot it asks to load the kernel.
I tried loading the kernel, but most of the code that I saw uses vmlinuz, which gives no response on my machine. So not sure how to load it.

In the past when I tried to install linux, it would lead me to an installation box, not GRUB. After some research, it seems that Huawei MXP doesn't supprot legacy boot, and uses UEFI, and that's why I'm led to a Grub page? I think. I'm not sure. 
Anyone knows how to install linux from a grub page?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Booting in UEFI you're supposed to see the Grub menu with options to "Try Ubuntu" and "Install..." among others. Is that what you see?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia No, it just gives a dark screen saying you can press "tab" for commands, but the commands are given all in one line, without any separation. No Try Ubuntu or Install, there is "boot" though

Comment: Is this it? https://consumer.huawei.com/en/laptops/matebook-x-pro/specs/ If so it's a perfectly normal laptop that should be installed in UEFI mode (the preinstalled Win10 already is). However it has a new Nvidia graphics that may require additional steps. If possible disable the Nvidia one in UEFI (still called "BIOS" but really isn't) so it boots and installs with the Intel Graphics (later, after installing the Nvidia drivers it can be re-enabled). Also in UEFI disable any reference to Legacy/CSM to assure that any installation media is booting in UEFI mode. >>>

Comment: >>> If the USB was correctly made it should boot to a Grub menu like I mentioned in the previous comment. Choose "Try Ubuntu" to enter the live session.